# Confusing appearance of unicode literals in NLTK stock texts

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, nlp, nltk

I've been starting to work through the 1st edition of *Natural Language Processing With Python* (2009), and have run into some odd behavior where my output doesn't match what the book is saying I should see.

For instance, consider the following example from the book (page 8):

[image]

Whenever I attempt to do the same thing, however, the output has every word as a unicode literal:

```
>>> sorted(set(text3))
[u'!', u"'", u'(', u')', u',', u',)', u'.', u'.)', u':', u';', u';)', u'?',
 u'?)', u'A', u'Abel', u'Abelmizraim', u'Abidah', u'Abide', u'Abimael', 
u'Abimelech', u'Abr', u'Abrah', u'Abraham', u'Abram', u'Accad', u'Achbor', u'Adah'...]
```

What's going on here?

Using Python 2.7.10 on Mac OS X 10.10.5 with NLTK version 3.0.4.

Comment: Presumably you are using a newer version than the book (which is six years old, after all) and that version produces unicode rather than bytes. Does it matter?

Comment: Good guess, @DanielRoseman: From [Natural Language Processing with Python](http://www.nltk.org/book) "The NLTK book is currently being updated for Python 3 and NLTK 3. This is work in progress; [...] A second edition of the book is anticipated in early 2016."

Comment: @DanielRoseman Unfortunately, you're probably in a better position to know whether it matters than I am.

Comment: Maybe read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and rejoice that NLTK is (finally) Python 3-compatible.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Found exactly this change in NLTK 3 in the [porting instructions on the nltk github](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Porting-your-code-to-NLTK-3.0). Apparently as of NLTK 3 all text is returned as unicode. If you want to flesh your comment out into an answer (I guess by including information like this) I'd be happy to accept it. (Unless this question turns out to be close-worthy by the rules of this SE.)

Comment: @PM2Ring Apparently, [the version of the book on the NLTK website](http://www.nltk.org/book/) has been updated for Python 3 and NLTK 3. I just really shouldn't be using the print edition.

Comment: Be glad it does this, or you'd be in for a world of hurt. Most natural languages tend to contain non-ASCII characters. For almost all purposes those Unicode strings have the same interface as byte strings. As a rule, whenever you have *text* in Python you should use Unicode strings and not byte strings.